# invoke audio recorder with intent and save voice in sdcard

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I try call the default audio recorder with intent and send path to audio recorder than save voice in my path in sdcard.I use this code:

```
File audioFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/nabege" + File.separator + "audio"
            + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".amr");
    Uri audioUri = Uri.fromFile(audioFile);
    record_audio_Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, audioUri);
    startActivityForResult(record_audio_Intent, 0);
```

This app  save voice in  default path. This path (nabege/audio) created in sdcard and exist.Please help

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: I want recorded voice save in sdcard/nabege/audio  but it save in default path.

Comment: try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Comment: I  change my code like this :File audioFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()  + "/nabege" + File.separator + "audio"
    + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".m4a");   But it do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound recording via intent always saves the recorded file to root of sdcard (or to a default path). Also, this intent may not be supported in certain phone models.

You must use MediaRecorder directly if you want to save recorded files to your custom paths.

Like this:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = null;

private void startRecording(File file) {
   if (recorder != null) {
      recorder.release();
   }
   recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   recorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
   recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
   try {
      recorder.prepare();
      recorder.start();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("giftlist", "io problems while preparing [" +
            file.getAbsolutePath() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Comment: Can  I pause  audio  record in this way? if your answer is yes : how do this?

Comment: MediaRecorder does not have pause and resume methods. You need to use stop and start methods instead. One way you can do this is: You can record raw data to a temporary file and when you want to pause, stop recording and append the output to your actual target file and endode the whole raw data at the end of recoding session. This is a bit trickey - but there is an example here: https://github.com/lassana/continuous-audiorecorder

Comment: Thank you.I try use this sample.

Comment: In this project (github) used  com.googlecode library. How to add this library  to  myproject?

Comment: Assuming you are using eclipse, I can tell you a shortcut (if you do no want to deal with Maven build system). Download the jar file from here: https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/downloads/detail?name=isoviewer-2.0-RC-17.jar&can=2&q=label%3AFeatured  (ignore the warning). Copy the downloaded jar to the libs folder in your eclipse workspace.

Comment: Now exist two problem.The import  com.googlecode.mp4parser.FileDataSourceImpl cannot be resolved   . The import com.coremedia.iso.boxes.Container cannot be resolved